# how to make this lowercase and uppercase

Tags: c++, string, encryption

I am making an encryption program based on [Vigenere cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher).

I am stuck on the lowercase and uppercase part.

For instance, if I wanted to encrypt/decrypt the text:

```
"This is a STRING"
```

The uppercase letters encrypt/decrypt fine, but the lowercase letters do not decrypt correctly. Also, the key that I use is all uppercase. Shouldn't the code below work for uppercase and lowercase?

```
if (isupper(OriginalText[i])) {
    int x = (OriginalText[i] + key[i]) % 26;
    x = x + 'A';

    EncryptText.push_back((x));
} else if (islower(OriginalText[i])) {
    int y = (OriginalText[i] + key[i]) % 26;

    y = y + 'a';

    EncryptText.push_back((y));
}
```

Below is for decryption:

```
if (EncryptedText[i] != space[j]) {

    if (isupper(EncryptedText[i])) {
        int x = (EncryptedText[i] - key[i] + 26) % 26;
        x += 'A';

        DecryptedText.push_back((x));
    } else if (islower(EncryptedText[i])) {
        int y = (EncryptedText[i] - key[i] + 26) % 26;
        y += 'a';

        DecryptedText.push_back((y));
    }
}
```

EDIT: Instead of the above code, I tried approaching it with the code below in order to cover all aspects.

- Uppercase text with Uppercase key
- Uppercase text with Lowercase key
- Lowercase text with Uppercase key
- Lowercase text with Lowercase key

I was able to get these two conditions to work:

- Uppercase text with Uppercase key
- Uppercase text with Lowercase key

So, I know a lowercase cipher key will work.
Now, I need to get these conditions to work:

- Lowercase text with Uppercase key
- Lowercase text with Lowercase key

Here is the code below:

```
        if (EncryptedText[i] != space[j]) {

        if (isupper(EncryptedText[i]) && isupper(key[i])) {
            x = ((((EncryptedText[i] + 'A') - (key[i] - 'A')) % 26) + 'A');
            DecryptedText.push_back(x);
        }
        if (isupper(EncryptedText[i]) && islower(key[i])) {
            x = ((((EncryptedText[i] + 'A') - (key[i] - 'a')) % 26) + 'A');
            DecryptedText.push_back(x);
        }
        if (islower(EncryptedText[i]) && isupper(key[i])) {
            x = ((((EncryptedText[i] + 'a') - (key[i] + 'A')) % 26) + 'a');
            DecryptedText.push_back(x);
        }
        if (islower(EncryptedText[i]) && islower(key[i])) {
            x = ((((EncryptedText[i] + 'a') - (key[i] + 'a')) % 26) + 'a');
            DecryptedText.push_back(x);
        }
```

I need help with last two if statements.

BELOW IS A LINK TO REDDIT WHICH HAS A LINK TO THE GITHUB PROJECT:
https://www.reddit.com/r/CodingHelp/comments/91c3tv/need_some_help_on_vigenere_cipher_program/

Comment: where is your decryption logic ?

Comment: I would have expected `int x = ((OriginalText[i] - 'A') + key[i]) % 26;` in the _isupper_ block and `int y = ((OriginalText[i] - 'a') + key[i]) % 26;` in the _islower_ block.

Comment: @Wyck I just tried it. It didn't work. The lowercase and the uppercase letters are both incorrect now. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why would you attempt to encrypt/decrypt a lower-case letter with an upper-case key and vice versa? Your key and character must be of the same case or you will attempt to read beyond the 26 character bounds of the *tabula recta* (the table).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin At which part did i mismatch the keys?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Are you saying that the lowercase text must only be paired with a lowercase key and an uppercase text must only be pair with a uppercase key?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you have an additional 32 in your table offset calculations that won't `mod 26` correctly. It looks like you have tried to address that in decrypt, but it is unclear if it was correct.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My last if-statement has a case with both the text and the key being lowercase. However, it still does not work. Have you tried the entire code on my github?

Comment: The trick is to force the key to match the input case on encoding, and then when decoding force the key to match the cipher case. E.g. to encode, `if (islower(c)) cipherc = (tolower (*k) - 'a' + c - 'a') % 26 + 'a';`. Then decoding (in addition to matching case) you need to check if `C - K >= 0` use `(C - K) % 26 + 'A';` otherwise `C - K + 26 + 'A';`.

Comment: Here is one I wrote in C just playing with the wikipedia algorithm [C Vigenere Cipher](http://paste.opensuse.org/79041707)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I just tried your idea of matching the cases. In my KeyGenerator function when i tried to match the case, I found out that the Keyword does not response to tolower or toupper initially. For instance, if the keyword was "STRING", and the text was all lowercase, initially the keyword would match as upper case. Then, After it has gone thru all the characters in the key it then response to tolower. So, it would go "STRINGstringstring".

Comment: Pay close attention to the use of `'+'` and the use of `'%'` in the decoding routines. You can compile the code I linked to and see case is preserved in both the encryption and decryption. (note, the example does not handle anything but `A-Za-z`).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I looked at the+ and % signs in my code. I tried changing them up as well. It's weird that uppercase text and lowercase key will work fine, but lowercase text and lowercase key will not work.

Comment: It has to do with taking `% 26` and the **magnitude** of the ASCII values. Take `'A'` and `'L'`  (`(65 + 76) % 26 = 11`) where `11 + 'A' = 'L'`. Now take lowercase (`(97 + 108) % 26 = 23`) where `23 + 'a' = 'x'`. All lowercase values are larger by `32` (or `1 << 5`) and the same `% 26` produces wildly different results. Now you can subtract `32` from the intermediate calculation and achieve the same result, or you can just reduce the ASCII values to index from `0` as explained in the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read the [Vigenere cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher), you are limited to a single 26x26 table for encoding. (at least as explained in the Wikipedia page). That means you have no way to mix and uppercase key with a lowercase character or vice versa, without making the cases match.

You are free to add to the cipher to extend the "tabula recta, Vigenère square, or Vigenère table" to include lowercase character resulting in a 52x52 and build the offset gymnastics into your cipher -- but then it wouldn't be the Vigenere cipher.

That doesn't mean you can't handle both uppercase and lowercase characters, you just have to make the key/character case-consistent for both encoding and decoding. You can do that by simply using the `tolower` or `toupper` conversions as you work through the encoding/decoding, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    string  key = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "LEMON",
            line,       /* input to encode */
            cipher,     /* encoded input  */
            decode;     /* decoded cipher */
    auto& k = key;
    size_t kdx = 0;        /* key index */

    if (!k[kdx]) {  /* validate key has at least one char */
        cerr << "invalid key.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline (cin, line)) {   /* read each line of input */
        /* encode line into cipher */
        for (auto& c : line) {      /* for each char in input */
            if (islower(c))         /* if lower, force key lower */
                cipher.push_back((tolower(k[kdx]) - 'a' + c - 'a') % 26 + 'a');
            else if (isupper (c))   /* if upper, force key upper */
                cipher.push_back((toupper(k[kdx]) - 'A' + c - 'A') % 26 + 'A');
            else {  /* otherwise -- character not supported */
                cerr << "error: unsupported char '" << c << "' removing.\n";
                continue;
            }
            kdx++;  /* increment key index */
            if (kdx == key.length())    /* if end of key, reset key index */
                kdx = 0;
        }
        /* decode cipher into decode */
        kdx = 0;                    /* reset key index */
        for (auto& c : cipher) {    /* for each char in cipher */
            if (islower (c)) {      /* if lower, force key lower */
                int off = c - tolower (k[kdx]);
                if (off >= 0)       /* if offset >= 0, mod 26 */
                    decode.push_back (off % 26 + 'a');
                else                /* if offset < 0, + 26 */
                    decode.push_back (off + 26 + 'a');
            }
            else if (isupper (c)) { /* do the same for upper case */
                int off = c - toupper (k[kdx]);
                if (off >= 0)
                    decode.push_back (off % 26 + 'A');
                else
                    decode.push_back (off + 26 + 'A');        
            }
            else {  
                cerr << "error: invalid char in cipher '" << c << "'.\n";
                return 1;
            }
            kdx++;  /* increment key index */
            if (kdx == key.length())    /* if end of key, reset key index */
                kdx = 0;
        }
        cout << "input : " << line << '\n' <<
                "key   : " << key <<  '\n' <<
                "cipher: " << cipher << '\n' <<
                "decode: " << decode << '\n';

        cipher.clear();     /* clear both cipher and decode */
        decode.clear();
        kdx = 0;            /* reset key index */
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using the example provided on the Wikipedia page, and forcing the case-consistency, you can encode and decode upper and lower case characters (it's just the same cipher preserving upper/lower case of the original string)

```
$ echo "ATTACKATDAWN" | ./bin/vigenere
input : ATTACKATDAWN
key   : LEMON
cipher: LXFOPVEFRNHR

$ echo "AttackAtDawn" | ./bin/vigenere lEMoN
input : AttackAtDawn
key   : lEMoN
cipher: LxfopvEfRnhr
decode: AttackAtDawn

$ echo "Attack At Dawn" | ./bin/vigenere lEMoN
error: unsupported char ' ' removing.
error: unsupported char ' ' removing.
input : Attack At Dawn
key   : lEMoN
cipher: LxfopvEfRnhr
decode: AttackAtDawn
```

Answer (score 0):

Well walk through ur code with an example. Lets take the text 'a'. It has a value of 97 according to the ascii table I found. 
assuming Encrypted[i] == 'a'

I'm also going to assume your DecryptedText is of char types.

```
int y = (97 - key[i] + 26) % 26
y = y + 97;
```

I don't know what your key[i] is. Do the math with your key[i] and see if the behavior is expected.

One very simple way to do this esp when you are beginner is to just insert some print statements in there

```
int y = (97 - key[i] + 26) % 26
std::cout << key[i] << " <-- is the key value;
y = y + 97;
std::cout << y << " <-- resulting y value".
```

Comment: I'm using type string for the program

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the two sets of letters (upper and lower) back to back to form a longer version of your alphabet and decimate on that.  Or alternatively simplify it and just use a single case for your cipher which will work just as fine.  You'll just have to make your letters "toUpper" or toLower before parsing through the logic.